# How to convert 2021-04-10 to 2021-04-11 increase day+1 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, date

```php
public function search_sale(searchRequest $request) {
    return $request->date2;
}
```

When `return` it, it is showing `2021-04-10` but I want it to show `2021-04-11`. How can I do it?

Comment: What is the real date saved ? I am pretty sure it is displaying `2021-04-10` because of daytime, you have not set the correct GTM/UTC zone... Explain more about `date2` please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Carbon`, check below

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

public function search_sale(searchRequest $request) {
    $date = Carbon::createFromDate($request->date2)->addDay();

    return $date->toDateString();
}
```

You can also add multiple days e.g. `->addDays(3)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strtotime()` function to modify the date.

```
public function search_sale ( searchRequest $request ){
    $date = $request->date2;
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day'));
}
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-examples) to learn more `strtotime()` function.

Comment: Do not use `strtotime` when you have `Carbon`... that is not the Laravel way... 2 out of 10 devs knows how to use that...

Comment: Laravel has Carbon to play with date and time which has  fantastic methods.